# Firebird Data Source form close after I start typing

Tags: visual-studio, ado.net, firebird, ddex

I am trying to add database through server explorer. I have installed DDEX and ADO.NET, then in Visual studio in project I added SqlClient via NuGet. When I go to Server Explorer > Connect to Database > Firebird Data Source, and then I start typing, on first input the window just closes.

I tried changing versions in machine.config, deleting multi lines in machine.config but nothing is working. I also tried reinstalling everything (except Visual Studio) but it is still not working.

Here is my spec:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015
- Firebird 3.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not know what was the problem. I reinstalled windows and it is working now :)

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you have several Firebird .net provider entries in the machine.config. [The Installer doesn't remove them](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-560).

So run noptepad as admin, open the file `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`

and make sure that under the `<DbProviderFactories>` node you only see 1 entry:

```
<add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3750abcc3150b00c"/>
```

It can also happen if you have a version missmatch from the referenced Firebird provider version and the one you have [installed via MSI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/). Both must be the same version. If you have installed [5.6 via MSI installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/5.6.0.0/), also install the [5.6 packages via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Firebird/5.6.0).